# Periodic timer sometimes delays and does not work intentionally flutter

Tags: flutter, memory, timer

Timers in flutter behave differently than expected.
If I call a specific function for each cycle in millisecond units,
it may lag behind the cycle.
Even if I tested only timers without other code, it did.
When I tested with other code, the degree of delay became severe.
It would be okay if does delay stays at ~99 milliseconds,
However it jumps to 100~1000 milliseconds if i use timer in my application.

I tested with Timer(dart:async), Metronome(Quiver library), Timer(dart:async) in Isolate.
An interesting phenomenon is, when i set those timers with same period and started,
those timers delays similar duration at similar moment.
For example, when I tested those timers in my application code, those three delays 1000 milliseconds at the same time. (large usage of memory ?)

Below is the test code. I'm testing on Galaxy Tab S4.(real device)

How can i use timer in milliseconds units?

```
//code for isolate
DateTime lastIsolate;
DateTime currentIsolate;
int isolateCounter = 0;

void timerTest(SendPort sendPort){
  print("Start Timer");

  lastIsolate = DateTime.now();
  Timer timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 20), checkTimerPeriod);
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();

  sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);
  receivePort.listen((message){
    if(message is bool){
      timer.cancel();
    }
  });
}

void checkTimerPeriod(Timer timer){
  currentIsolate = DateTime.now();
  Duration diff = currentIsolate.difference(lastIsolate);
  if(diff.inMilliseconds > 30){
    isolateCounter++;
    print("${DateTime.now()}] Isolate :: ${diff.inMilliseconds}, $isolateCounter times");
  }
  lastIsolate = currentIsolate;
}

void main() {
  ensureInitializedForSharedPreference();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]) ;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

void ensureInitializedForSharedPreference(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() ;
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  Isolate isolate;
  ReceivePort _receivePort = ReceivePort();
  DateTime _lastTimer;
  DateTime _currentTimer;
  DateTime _lastMetronome;
  DateTime _currentMetronome;
  Timer timer;
  StreamSubscription<DateTime> metronome;
  int timerCounter;
  int metronomeCounter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timerCounter = 0;
    metronomeCounter = 0;
    startTimers();
    spawnIsolate();
  }

  void startTimers(){
    _lastTimer = DateTime.now();
    _lastMetronome = DateTime.now();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 20), timerCheck) ;
    metronome = Metronome.epoch(aMillisecond * 20).listen((event) {
      metronomeCheck();
    });
  }

  void timerCheck(Timer timer){
    _currentTimer = DateTime.now();
    Duration diff = _currentTimer.difference(_lastTimer);
    if(diff.inMilliseconds > 30){
      timerCounter++;
      print("${DateTime.now()}] Timer :: ${diff.inMilliseconds}, $timerCounter times");
    }
    _lastTimer = _currentTimer;
  }

  void metronomeCheck(){
    _currentMetronome = DateTime.now();
    Duration diff = _currentMetronome.difference(_lastMetronome);
    if(diff.inMilliseconds > 30){
      metronomeCounter++;
      print("${DateTime.now()}] Metronome :: ${diff.inMilliseconds}, $metronomeCounter times");
    }
    _lastMetronome = _currentMetronome;
  }

  void spawnIsolate() async {
    isolate = await Isolate.spawn(timerTest, _receivePort.sendPort);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TimerTestPage()
//      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class TimerTestPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TimerTestPageState();
  }
}

class TimerTestPageState extends State<TimerTestPage>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

**Print Result:**

```
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:54.002557] Metronome :: 99, 2 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:54.002805] Timer :: 91, 2 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:54.137470] Timer :: 45, 3 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:54.137680] Metronome :: 35, 3 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:54.456208] Metronome :: 34, 4 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:55.063127] Metronome :: 38, 5 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:55.108351] Timer :: 37, 4 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:55.209915] Metronome :: 67, 6 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:55.210140] Timer :: 56, 5 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:58.800702] Metronome :: 49, 7 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:58.801505] Timer :: 50, 6 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:58.845783] Isolate :: 49, 2 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:59.838194] Timer :: 40, 7 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:00:59.838950] Metronome :: 35, 8 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:00.835309] Metronome :: 52, 9 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:00.837709] Timer :: 44, 8 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:01.779771] Metronome :: 37, 10 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:02.802442] Metronome :: 59, 11 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:02.803132] Timer :: 51, 9 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:02.827479] Isolate :: 31, 3 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:03.800940] Metronome :: 52, 12 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:03.801845] Timer :: 49, 10 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:03.835860] Isolate :: 39, 4 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:04.860201] Timer :: 66, 11 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:04.860752] Metronome :: 57, 13 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:04.871719] Isolate :: 35, 5 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:05.797080] Metronome :: 54, 14 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:05.798653] Timer :: 46, 12 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:06.798412] Metronome :: 51, 15 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:06.799347] Timer :: 47, 13 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:07.802850] Metronome :: 52, 16 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:07.803528] Timer :: 52, 14 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:07.832428] Isolate :: 36, 6 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:08.798311] Metronome :: 56, 17 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:08.802467] Timer :: 50, 15 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:09.810389] Timer :: 58, 16 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:09.811026] Metronome :: 48, 18 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:09.835066] Isolate :: 38, 7 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:10.810530] Metronome :: 65, 19 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:10.812136] Timer :: 60, 17 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:10.830197] Isolate :: 34, 8 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:11.810372] Timer :: 48, 18 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:11.810956] Metronome :: 48, 20 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:11.826718] Isolate :: 31, 9 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:12.802337] Timer :: 50, 19 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:12.810522] Metronome :: 47, 21 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:12.841223] Isolate :: 44, 10 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:13.631729] Timer :: 36, 20 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:13.801782] Metronome :: 58, 22 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:13.802542] Timer :: 50, 21 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:13.835463] Isolate :: 39, 11 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:14.789602] Timer :: 35, 22 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:15.754015] Metronome :: 31, 23 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:15.811248] Isolate :: 35, 12 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:16.753175] Timer :: 36, 23 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:16.787876] Metronome :: 33, 24 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:16.791421] Timer :: 34, 24 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:17.839036] Metronome :: 55, 25 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:17.842928] Timer :: 51, 25 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:17.871998] Isolate :: 35, 13 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:18.804048] Timer :: 52, 26 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:18.804922] Metronome :: 41, 26 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:18.836156] Isolate :: 39, 14 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:19.796440] Metronome :: 45, 27 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:19.797077] Timer :: 45, 27 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:20.755218] Metronome :: 31, 28 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:20.794793] Timer :: 37, 28 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:20.798211] Metronome :: 36, 29 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:21.803089] Metronome :: 59, 30 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:21.803601] Timer :: 51, 29 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:22.283024] Timer :: 32, 30 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:22.755033] Metronome :: 31, 31 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:22.790614] Metronome :: 35, 32 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:22.794945] Timer :: 38, 31 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:22.815671] Isolate :: 39, 15 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:23.163503] Timer :: 31, 32 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:23.795069] Metronome :: 51, 33 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:23.795837] Timer :: 43, 33 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:23.841426] Isolate :: 43, 16 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:24.795185] Metronome :: 49, 34 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:24.795927] Timer :: 44, 34 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:25.804665] Timer :: 52, 35 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:25.805359] Metronome :: 41, 35 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:25.831298] Isolate :: 35, 17 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:26.806900] Metronome :: 39, 36 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:26.807681] Timer :: 35, 36 times
I/flutter (11728): 2020-11-18 18:01:26.832718] Isolate :: 36, 18 times
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Timer.periodic` documentation:

> The exact timing depends on the underlying timer implementation. No more than n callbacks will be made in duration * n time, but the time between two consecutive callbacks can be shorter and longer than duration.

The `Timer` in dart isn't intended to be as accurate as you seem to be expecting.

Comment: Is there any alternative you could recommend?

Comment: If you are updating a Widget, you can use a Ticker, which will allow you to update on every frame (60 times per second). I don't believe there is a way for more precision than 60 ticks per second as Flutter is not designed for it.

Comment: [Here](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-timer-vs-ticker) is a good explanantion & example.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I saw this already but sadly I'm not updating a widget but instead playing a sound. So this does not help :(

Comment: Ah. How frequently do you need the sound to play? You may can still use Ticker to time it.

Comment: @novas1r1 Check [this](https://gist.github.com/mitsuoka/2652622) out for a more accurate timer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Lee3 is absolutely correct. The Timer.periodic works as designed. But if you need to work the Timer.periodic to work more reliable when it comes to a consistent tickrate check out this little package: [reliable_periodic_timer](https://github.com/1nf0rmatix/reliable_interval_timer).

It uses the Timer.periodic under the hood but checks based on the current millisecond if it's already the correct time to fire.

It's used like this:

```
ReliableIntervalTimer(
    interval: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    callback: (elapsedMilliseconds) => print('elapsedMilliseconds: $elapsedMilliseconds');,
);
```

Comment: I like this package it is more reliable as it's owner says, but there are also some problems with disposing and stoping it, they are also related to Flutter bugs and problems. For example timer doesn't stop on push screen